# Does a foreach loop work directly with a JSonStore data object store?

Tags: dojo, jsonstore

I create a JSonStore with a JSON formatted array of objects.
I have verified it is properly formatted.

I then try to use a dojo forEach loop on it but the JSonStore doesn't seem to have any data in it. I can specify the target in my web page URL and it shows the right data. But using console.log(myJsonStore) shows an object but I don't see the data in Firebug. I also don't see any GET for the service providing the data. It's like specifying the target path in a URL in the browser fires the GET but not when I try to trigger it in the postCreate where my foreach is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from Ricardo, i believe is a little incorrect, seeing as the JsonRest.query function returns a dojo.Deferred.

You have a REST call being made asynchroniously through store read api - and once it returns values, it will promise to run whats set as the callback.

Try this for your loop iterator instead

```
storeObj.query( {} ).then(function ( results ) {
  dojo.forEach( results, function( obj ) {
    console.log( obj );
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks to @ricardo_garza_v and @mschr! I found both worked but I would guess that mschr is more correct given the async nature of the query.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
var storeObj = new JsonRest({
    target: "/some/resource"
});
storeObj.query({}).forEach(function(obj){console.log(obj);});
```

that should do the trick